# is it safe to remove language files to save space in osx?

Tags: macos

It seems like by removing Language Files I can save about 1.18Gb space.

I did a google on this and I find conflicting views regarding this.

[image]

I don't need these language files. I just want to confirm it is side-effect free

Comment: I have not tried it recently and why I'm posting this as a comment then an answer. It was my experience that removing language files for other then my language caused various issues and was not worth the relatively small amount of space they took up. YMMV

Comment: It has been YEARS since I tried this, because when I did it I had a variety of problems with the Mac afterwards. Maybe it was the utility or maybe it was removing the files, either way, unless you are DESPERATE for more space, just leave 'em there.

Comment: Some people have done this without problems, but there are also various cases in the Apple forums where users have  really messed up their systems.  Like Steve, I aways recommend leaving them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to provide an actual answer to this, even if it is speculative...

Like some of the commenters, I've also tried this in the past, with varying results. I don't remember specifically which apps were affected, but it was sufficient that I needed to reinstall some.

I'd say on balance it's simply not worth the risk/effort, balanced against the amount of space they take up on your drive.

I will also add that a lot of those clean-up apps like to invent 'problems' that they can 'solve' for you, in order to justify their existence.